# How to use printf to output %c

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I want to output **Unknown: %r** in the following code but I keep getting errors how can I bypass it

```
printf("Unknown:[%r]\n");
```

I keep getting identifier %r not found.

Comment: Use `%%` to output a literal `%`

Comment: better use `puts("Unknown:[%r]")` if you don't use any formatting and just print a plain string